# Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/ng/areq?p0=CustomersController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-route

I have practice project in angular js, 
**Description**

1. demoangular.html page
2. Logout.html page

demoangular page is login page it redirects to logout.html

But logout.html doesnt behave properly

it shows following error on console

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/ng/areq?p0=CustomersController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:52078/scripts/angular.min.js:6:450
    at tb (http://localhost:52078/scripts/angular.min.js:18:360)
    at Pa (http://localhost:52078/scripts/angular.min.js:18:447)
    at http://localhost:52078/scripts/angular.min.js:62:17
    at http://localhost:52078/scripts/angular.min.js:49:43
    at q (http://localhost:52078/scripts/angular.min.js:7:386)
    at H (http://localhost:52078/scripts/angular.min.js:48:406)
    at f (http://localhost:52078/scripts/angular.min.js:42:399)
    at http://localhost:52078/scripts/angular.min.js:42:67 angular.min.js:8203
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/".
```

following is code ...

**Demoangular.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="customerApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular js</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var demoapp = angular.module('customerApp', ['ngRoute']);
        demoapp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/hello', {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'partials/hello.html'
            });
            $routeProvider.when('/logout', {
                controller: 'newController',
                templateUrl: 'partials/logout.html'
            });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/hello' });
        });

        demoapp.factory("authser", function ($location, $http) {
            return {
                login: function (cardentials) {
                    if (cardentials.username != "jot") {
                        alert("its ");
                    }
                    else {

                        $location.path('/logout');

                    }
                },
                logout: function () {
                    $location.path('/hello');
                }
            }
        })

        demoapp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, authser) {
            $scope.cardentials = { username: "", password: "" };

            $scope.login = function () {
                authser.login($scope.cardentials);
            };

        });
        demoapp.controller('newController', function ($scope, authser) {
            $scope.logout = function () {
                authser.logout();

            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>I am Inside the Angular Knowledge</h1>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="logout()">logout</button>


    <style>
        #mydiv {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1000;
            background-color: grey;
            opacity: .8;
        }
    </style>
    <div data-ng-controller="CustomersController" class="container">

        <strong class="error">{{ error }}</strong>
        <p data-ng-hide="addMode">
            <a data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a>

        </p>
        <form name="addCustomer" data-ng-show="addMode" style="width: 600px; margin: 0px auto;">
            <label>Name:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="newcustomer.Name" required />
            <label>Email:</label><input type="email" data-ng-model="newcustomer.Email" required />
            <br />
            <span class="error" data-ng-show="addCustomer.$error.email">Invalid Email format!</span>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" data-ng-click="add()" data-ng-disabled="!addCustomer.$valid" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <br />
            <br />
        </form>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 800px">
            <tr>
                <th>#id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="search.Name" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="search.Email" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:search">
                <td><strong data-ng-hide="customer.editMode">{{ customer.CustomerID }}</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="customer.editMode">{{ customer.Name }}</p>
                    <p data-ng-show="customer.editMode">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="customer.Name" />
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="customer.editMode">{{ customer.Email }}</p>
                    <input data-ng-show="customer.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="customer.Email" /></td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="customer.editMode"><a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(customer)" href="javascript:;">Edit</a> | <a data-ng-click="delcustomer(customer)" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></p>
                    <p data-ng-show="customer.editMode"><a data-ng-click="save(customer)" href="javascript:;">Save</a> | <a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(customer)" href="javascript:;">Cancel</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('customerApp', []);
        var url = 'api/Customers/';

        app.factory('customerFactory', function ($http) {
            return {
                getCustomer: function () {
                    return $http.get(url);
                },
                addCustomer: function (customer) {
                    return $http.post(url, customer);
                },
                deleteCustomer: function (customer) {
                    return $http.delete(url + customer.CustomerID);
                },
                updateCustomer: function (customer) {
                    return $http.put(url + customer.Id, customer);
                }
            };
        });

        app.controller('CustomersController', function PostsController($scope, customerFactory) {
            $scope.customers = [];
            //$scope.loading = true;
            $scope.addMode = false;

            $scope.toggleEdit = function () {
                this.customer.editMode = !this.customer.editMode;
            };
            $scope.toggleAdd = function () {
                $scope.addMode = !$scope.addMode;
            };
            $scope.save = function () {
                //$scope.loading = true;
                var cust = this.customer;
                customerFactory.updateCustomer(cust).success(function (data) {
                    alert("Saved Successfully!!");
                    cust.editMode = false;
                    //$scope.loading = false;
                }).error(function (data) {
                    $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving customer! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
                    //$scope.loading = false;

                });
            };

            // add Customer
            $scope.add = function () {
                $scope.loading = true;
                customerFactory.addCustomer(this.newcustomer).success(function (data) {
                    alert("Added Successfully!!");
                    $scope.addMode = false;
                    $scope.customers.push(data);
                    //$scope.loading = false;
                }).error(function (data) {
                    $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding customer! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
                    //$scope.loading = false;

                });
            };
            // delete Customer
            $scope.delcustomer = function () {
                //$scope.loading = true;
                var currentCustomer = this.customer;
                customerFactory.deleteCustomer(currentCustomer).success(function (data) {
                    alert("Deleted Successfully!!");
                    $.each($scope.customers, function (i) {
                        if ($scope.customers[i].CustomerID === currentCustomer.CustomerID) {
                            $scope.customers.splice(i, 1);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    //$scope.loading = false;
                }).error(function (data) {
                    $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving customer! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
                    //$scope.loading = false;

                });
            };

            //get all Customers
            customerFactory.getCustomer().success(function (data) {
                $scope.customers = data;
                //$scope.loading = false;
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
                //$scope.loading = false;
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forgot `data-ng-app="customerApp"` in _logout.html_

Comment: methinks, error in your route configs

Comment: can you provide url whither you redirects? i think you stay on the same page and as you config route try load _logout.html_ as template url, and try process it with `newController`

Comment: if you have a time i tell you the concept from start to end @Grundy

Comment: you can also add it to OP :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54711/discussion-between-grundy-and-jatt-net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `CustomersController` on *logout.html* inside module *"customerApp"*, but forgot add `data-ng-app="customerApp"` to *html* tag on this page.
So you need add in *logout.html*

```
<html data-ng-app="customerApp">
```

Comment: i added but same issue resides @

Comment: Have you tried the following?
  
`<html data-ng-app="customer-app">`  
  
Assuming AngularJS is consistent, then when you have camel-cased names they must be reference in views as hyphenated.  This is certainly the case with directives, but I can't say that I've named my app modules anything other than 'app' in most cases.

Comment: @natwallbank, i'm based on worked `Demoangular.html`

Comment: solved @Grundy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933501/angular-page-loads-again-and-again/23934895#23934895

Comment: @Grundy are you around

Comment: @Jatt.net-Born2Code what you mean? :-)

Comment: i solved the problem now the app is fine @Grundy ... i wana appreciate you help

Comment: @Jot, could you explain how you fixed the problem? I tried to click on the link and that does not exist any more.

Comment: @SharminJose do you have a same problem? you can create your own question, and we try help you :-)

Comment: @SharminJose , i was on christmas vacations , please have a look over the link i undelete that post

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration for CustomersController looks wrong.  You've specified:

```
app.controller('CustomersController', function PostsController($scope, customerFactory) { .. });
```

It should be:

```
app.controller('CustomersController', function ($scope, customerFactory) { .. });
```

The other problem I see is with the following:

`<button type="button" data-ng-click="logout()">logout</button>`

There's no controller / scope context on which to call a logout() function.  It looks as though you're handling this via routing, in which case you should just have a link to logout, e.g.

`<a href="/logout">Logout</a>`

It's worth noting that this will still not solve your problem.  It'll load your `newController` and the logout partial.  At that point you'll still want something to call the logout function on newController, e.g. some kind of confirmation.

Comment: plz have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933501/angular-page-loads-again-and-again/23934895#23934895

Answer (score 0):

Sometime we use same module name in factory,controllers and main module.so, this is main reason it will give error Error: [ng:areq] Argument,don't use same module name when u call calling your services,controllers,factory.