# Angular , page loads again and again

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-route

i have a simple project of angularjs.

**Problem**
after login when i redirected to login.html , it continuously sends request and page is reloaded again and again

please help following is code

demoangular.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="customerApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular js</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

HEllo.html

```
    <h1>Welcome To Angular</h1>
    <form id="main" data-ng-submit="login()">
        <input name="name"  id="user" type="text"    data-ng-model="cardentials.username" required />
        <input name="url" id="pass" type="password" data-ng-model="cardentials.password" required />

        <button>new</button>
    </form>
```

logout.html

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <style>
        #mydiv {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1000;
            background-color: grey;
            opacity: .8;
        }

        .ajax-loader {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: -32px; /* -1 * image width / 2 */
            margin-top: -32px; /* -1 * image height / 2 */
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

     <button type="button" data-ng-click="logout()">logout</button>
    <div data-ng-controller="CustomersController" class="container">

        <strong class="error">{{ error }}</strong>
        <!--<div id="mydiv" data-ng-show="loading">
            <img src="Images/482.gif" class="ajax-loader" />
        </div>-->
        <p data-ng-hide="addMode">
            <a data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a>

        </p>
        <form name="addCustomer" data-ng-show="addMode" style="width: 600px; margin: 0px auto;">
            <label>Name:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="newcustomer.Name" required />
            <label>Email:</label><input type="email" data-ng-model="newcustomer.Email" required />
            <br />
            <span class="error" data-ng-show="addCustomer.$error.email">Invalid Email format!</span>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" data-ng-click="add()" data-ng-disabled="!addCustomer.$valid" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <br />
            <br />
        </form>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 800px">
            <tr>
                <th>#id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="search.Name" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="search.Email" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:search">
                <td><strong data-ng-hide="customer.editMode">{{ customer.CustomerID }}</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="customer.editMode">{{ customer.Name }}</p>
                    <p data-ng-show="customer.editMode">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="customer.Name" />
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="customer.editMode">{{ customer.Email }}</p>
                    <input data-ng-show="customer.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="customer.Email" /></td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="customer.editMode"><a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(customer)" href="javascript:;">Edit</a> | <a data-ng-click="delcustomer(customer)" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></p>
                    <p data-ng-show="customer.editMode"><a data-ng-click="save(customer)" href="javascript:;">Save</a> | <a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(customer)" href="javascript:;">Cancel</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
    </div>
```

app.js

```
var demoapp = angular.module('customerApp', ['ngRoute']);
demoapp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/hello', {
        controller: 'SimpleController',
        templateUrl: 'partials/hello.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/logout', {
        controller: 'newController',
        templateUrl: '/logout.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/hello' });
});

demoapp.factory("authser", function ($location, $http) {
    return {
        login: function (cardentials) {
            if (cardentials.username != "jot") {
                alert("its ");
            }
            else {

                $location.path('/logout');

            }
        },
        logout: function () {
            $location.path('/hello');
        }
    }
})

demoapp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, authser) {
    $scope.cardentials = { username: "", password: "" };

    $scope.login = function () {
        authser.login($scope.cardentials);
    };

});
demoapp.controller('newController', function ($scope, authser) {
    $scope.logout = function () {
        authser.logout();

    };
});




var url = 'api/Customers/';

demoapp.factory('customerFactory', function ($http) {
    return {
        getCustomer: function () {
            return $http.get(url);
        },
        addCustomer: function (customer) {
            return $http.post(url, customer);
        },
        deleteCustomer: function (customer) {
            return $http.delete(url + customer.CustomerID);
        },
        updateCustomer: function (customer) {
            return $http.put(url + customer.Id, customer);
        }
    };
});

demoapp.controller('CustomersController', function PostsController($scope, customerFactory) {
    $scope.customers = [];
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.addMode = false;

    $scope.toggleEdit = function () {
        this.customer.editMode = !this.customer.editMode;
    };
    $scope.toggleAdd = function () {
        $scope.addMode = !$scope.addMode;
    };
    $scope.save = function () {
        //$scope.loading = true;
        var cust = this.customer;
        customerFactory.updateCustomer(cust).success(function (data) {
            alert("Saved Successfully!!");
            cust.editMode = false;
            $scope.loading = false;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving customer! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
            $scope.loading = false;

        });
    };

    // add Customer
    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        customerFactory.addCustomer(this.newcustomer).success(function (data) {
            alert("Added Successfully!!");
            $scope.addMode = false;
            $scope.customers.push(data);
            $scope.loading = false;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding customer! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
            $scope.loading = false;

        });
    };
    // delete Customer
    $scope.delcustomer = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        var currentCustomer = this.customer;
        customerFactory.deleteCustomer(currentCustomer).success(function (data) {
            alert("Deleted Successfully!!");
            $.each($scope.customers, function (i) {
                if ($scope.customers[i].CustomerID === currentCustomer.CustomerID) {
                    $scope.customers.splice(i, 1);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $scope.loading = false;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving customer! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
            $scope.loading = false;

        });
    };

    //get all Customers
    customerFactory.getCustomer().success(function (data) {
        $scope.customers = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });

});
```

Comment: You are using AngularJS routes with `ng-view` - this means that everything outside of `ng-view` is made available to all view templates. You should not declare the `html`, `head` and `body` tags for each template. Just keep the code that should go inside `ng-view`.

Comment: where html head body is not declared please? @callmekatootie

Comment: The problem is not that it is NOT declared. But that it is declared everywhere. `hello.html` and `logout.html` are templates. They should not have the `html`, `head` and `body` tags. Just keep the content of the page in the template.

Comment: plz edit the question and remove the tags that are not needed @callmekatootie

Comment: i do but nothing changes @callmekatootie

Comment: cheers @callmekatootie/.... solved after modifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

updated logout.html

@callmekatootie thanks for your help 
kudoo

```
<style>
        #mydiv {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1000;
            background-color: grey;
            opacity: .8;
        }

        .ajax-loader {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: -32px; /* -1 * image width / 2 */
            margin-top: -32px; /* -1 * image height / 2 */
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

     <button type="button" data-ng-click="logout()">logout</button>
    <div data-ng-controller="CustomersController" class="container">

        <strong class="error">{{ error }}</strong>
        <!--<div id="mydiv" data-ng-show="loading">
            <img src="Images/482.gif" class="ajax-loader" />
        </div>-->
        <p data-ng-hide="addMode">
            <a data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a>

        </p>
        <form name="addCustomer" data-ng-show="addMode" style="width: 600px; margin: 0px auto;">
            <label>Name:</label><input type="text" data-ng-model="newcustomer.Name" required />
            <label>Email:</label><input type="email" data-ng-model="newcustomer.Email" required />
            <br />
            <span class="error" data-ng-show="addCustomer.$error.email">Invalid Email format!</span>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" data-ng-click="add()" data-ng-disabled="!addCustomer.$valid" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <br />
            <br />
        </form>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 800px">
            <tr>
                <th>#id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="search.Name" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="search.Email" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:search">
                <td><strong data-ng-hide="customer.editMode">{{ customer.CustomerID }}</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="customer.editMode">{{ customer.Name }}</p>
                    <p data-ng-show="customer.editMode">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="customer.Name" />
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="customer.editMode">{{ customer.Email }}</p>
                    <input data-ng-show="customer.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="customer.Email" /></td>
                <td>
                    <p data-ng-hide="customer.editMode"><a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(customer)" href="javascript:;">Edit</a> | <a data-ng-click="delcustomer(customer)" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></p>
                    <p data-ng-show="customer.editMode"><a data-ng-click="save(customer)" href="javascript:;">Save</a> | <a data-ng-click="toggleEdit(customer)" href="javascript:;">Cancel</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
    </div>
```